# How to stop a while loop with a user input?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to make a dictionary with user input products and prices, but it won't stop when I type in stop? This is the message that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/faks/recnici, torke, skupovi/v1.py", line 7, in <module>
    y=eval(input("its price?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'stop' is not defined
```

This is the code:

```
d={}
x=""
y=""
d[x]=y
while x!="stop":
    x=input("product?(type stop if you want to stop)")
    y=eval(input("its price?"))
    d[x]=y
print(d)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: @quamrana thank you for responding! what do you mean exactly when you say traceback?

Comment: If you `eval` the string `"stop"`, you will get that error, because `stop` is not something that can be evaluated. Why don't you check if the string is `"stop"` _before_ you attempt to `eval` it?

Comment: When you say that the error is ‘NameError ...’ there is a lot more including at least one line of code. Include it all.

Comment: @khelwood thank you for your response! i changed it now, but my loop should stop when x (which isnt eval) is "stop"

Comment: Don't see why you have eval(...) at all.  Isn't the user just providing a price?  You should use float(...) to convert price to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you process the input you may need a slightly different approach to stop the loop:

```
d = {}
while True:
    x = input("product?(type stop if you want to stop)")
    if x == "stop":
        break
    y = input("its price?")
    d[x] = y
print(d)
```

Use `while True:` and then add a separate test to break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while True` loop and `break` from it if the condition is satisfied.

```
d={}
while True:
    product = input("product?(type stop if you want to stop)")
    if product == 'stop':
        break
    price = float(input("its price?"))
    d[product] = price
print(d)
```

I used more meaningful names for the variables, formatted the code according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  and removed the dangerous use of [`eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you `eval` the string `"stop"`, you will get that error, because `stop` is not something that can be evaluated.

Also you should avoid using `eval` to evaluate user input, because it is not safe.

```
d={}
x=""
y=""
while x!="stop":
    x=input("product?(type stop if you want to stop)")
    if x!="stop":
        d[x] = float(input("price?"))
print(d)
```

Comment: why x != 'stop' written twice?

Comment: One is the loop condition, one is preventing execution of certain lines within the loop. An alternative is to use a `break` statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {}
x = ""
y = ""
while True:
    x = input("product?(type stop if you want to stop)")
    if x != "stop":
        y = eval(input("its price?"))
        d[x] = y
    else:
        break



print(d)
```

Comment: You appear to have a break after your loop.

Comment: Now it just stopped after one product and the name "stop" isnt defined error is still there:/ thank you though!

Comment: @astudent try it now and tell me by results

Comment: Yes, it works now, but can still be simplified by reversing the `if` and removing the `else`